# How to connect a java client to a gRPC server running in android?

Tags: android, server, grpc

I am running gRPC server on android and want to call it from a java client from host pc. What would be the ip address for android device? The host pc and android device are in different networks.

I tried with `10.0.0.1, 10.0.0.2`

`HelloWorldClient client = new HelloWorldClient("10.0.2.2", 50051);`

Is there any default ip for android devices? How can I get it?

Comment: either put them into the same network segment or get a router.

Comment: Tried with same wi-fi network, getting connection timeout error. Router solution will be expensive.